# C#: null warning even though it's not possible

Tags: c#, null

Ok so here I have this function that can return a null value in some cases. However, even when testing if it is before, it still says it might be null.

My code:

```
if (Account.FindAccount(usernameInput) == null) { return; }    
if (Account.FindAccount(usernameInput).password == "1234") // warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference
{ 
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Even if the compiler saw the logic behind what you are doing and didn't give you a warning, why would you force the poor machine to have to find the account twice just for nullability? As others have pointed out, save the returned value into a variable. Or you could also do `Account.FindAccount(usernameInput)?.password == "1234"` if you want a one liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that `FindAccount` operation guaranteed to be idempotent?  The compiler has no such guarantee.  What it returns in one call it might not return in another.

More to the point... If *you* believe it will always return the same result for the same input, why are you invoking it twice?  Just invoke it once and store the result:

```
var account = Account.FindAccount(usernameInput);
if (account == null) { return; }    
if (account.password == "1234")
{ 
    //Do stuff
}
```